# Capybara isn't checking a checkbox in rspec feature test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec3

I am attempting to create a feature test where a checkbox needs to be checked and for whatever reason Capybara is not checking the box.

I am using:

rspec: 3.0.4 and capybara: 2.4.1

When I print out a snapshot of the view, the checkbox isn't checked.

When I run the checkbox code in pry it returns the string "checked" but when I print a snapshot the checkbox still is not checked and my test does not pass. I'm curious if there is another way to get this checkbox to check.

Here is my current code so far:

Feature Test:

```
background do
  discussion_group
  @user2 = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  add_user_to_user_role_for_group(group, @user2)
  admin_login
  add_user_to_admin_role_for_group(group, @user)
  visit groups_path
  click_on 'Email Group'
end

scenario 'sending a valid email' do
  valid_form
  expect(page).to have_content group_email_success_notification
  expect_count_of_deliveries_to_be 1
 end
```

Macro:

```
def valid_form
  fill_in 'group_email_subject', with: new_text
  fill_in 'group_email_body', with: Faker::Lorem.words(200).join("\s")
  check "group_email_#{@user2.id}_"
  click_on "Send Email"
end
```

The output of my test is that I must have 1 user selected meaning that I don't have a user checked. When I run the check line in console here is what I get:

```
[10] check('group_email_10_')
=> "checked"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

> page.check('insert #id, .class, or value')\
>   
> for example:
>   
> input type="checkbox" id="puppy_gooddog" name="puppy[gooddog]" value="yes"
>   
> page.check('puppy_gooddog') or page.check('puppy[gooddog]')

Comment: I did try using page.check and got the same result. I believe if I use the name, I would get an ambiguous error since all of the names of all the checkboxes are the same. The end result is all of the checked boxes are an array to be used in code. I am curious if this might be an issue with my version of Firefox and the selenium web driver. Since the recent firefox upgrade selenium web driver doesn't seem compatible and so I downgraded and things haven't necessarily been right from what I can tell.